# How to reference and declare a UINavigationController's custom method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

At the moment, I'm trying to call an existing UINavigationController's method from a scene.
My storyboard looks like:

> ->UINavigationController--(rootViewController)-->ViewController-->Scene

I need help understanding how to call the existing UINavigationController's custom method named showGameCenterMenu() from the scene. This is what I have so far:

> UINavigationController *navRef = self.view.window.rootViewController.navigationController;
>   [navController performSelector:@selector(showGameCenterMenu)];

I understand that my method call is probably incorrect, but any help would be appreciated understanding this and whether or not I'm breaking best practice by directly referencing this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the navigation controller is the root view controller then you are navigating too far (so you probably get `nil`), you should have:

```
UINavigationController *navRef = (UINavigationController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
```

*(with a cast from `UIViewController`)*

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Can you explain how (UINavigationController *) worked there? I have seen it very often in my time programming, and have never had a proper introduction to how that process works or what it means.. Is it the same as like type-casting an integer to a float except with a pointer to a type of object?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, it is a typecast. It was a pointer to a `UIViewController *` and the cast makes it a `UINavigationController *` (which works because that is what the instance really is at runtime and it's a subclass)

Answer (score 2):

Cast the pointer you're getting to your custom navigation controller class and then call its method.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the great guys in the comments I was able to find a suitable solution..
(NavigationViewController is my custom UINavigationController class);

> NavigationViewController *navRef = (NavigationViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
>   [navRef showGameCenterMenu];

This allowed me to send a method call to my NavigationViewController which displays the Game Center Menu one Layer above the existing View Controller by presenting it with .topViewController appended. Thanks again guys :)